# Angularjs table params are not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement first time AngularJs `NgTableParams` i was able to populate data into table but when i use `params.page()` etc methods its throwing errors, following issues i have witn `ng-table`.

1- So when i dont use params methods i was able to get data for table but i see error `$defer.resolve is not a function`.

2- When i use params i got error `can not read page its undefined`

Any idea how to resolve these issues , anything i am missing to set my table options in below code ?

ctrl.js

```
angular.module('loggingApp').controller('ditTableCtrl', function($scope, DitFactory, $filter, NgTableParams) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.logs = [];
    DitFactory.getLogs().then(function(response) {
        $scope.logs = response.data;
        console.log($scope.logs);
    });
    $scope.usersTable = new NgTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 10
    }, {
        total: $scope.logs.length,
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $scope.data = $scope.logs.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
            $defer.resolve($scope.data);
        }
    });
});
```

main.html

```
  <table ng-table="usersTable" class="table table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in data">
            <td data-title="'Id'" >
                {{user.id}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'First Name'" >
                {{user.first_name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Last Name'" >
                {{user.last_name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'e-mail'" >
                {{user.email}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Country'">
                {{user.country}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'IP'" >
                {{user.ip_address}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen $defer before. I think you want to use a promise in which case it would be $q.defer(), with defer as the method in the $q promise service. Something along these lines:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.resolve($scope.data);
```

Read up on promises first, there are several resources. Here's just a couple:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/deferred-and-promise.html